# Nesting Bootstrap input boxes side by side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two input boxes that I am trying to get side by side on the row but I'd like there still to be a gap between the boxes but flush to the sides of the container.

Is there a way using just Bootstrap to do this? The container is a replication of a mobile device.

```
<div class="group col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" name="first-name" ng-model="user.firstname" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" name="last-name" ng-model="user.surname" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MwGilYn9dFHSMJBikfu1?p=preview)

Comment: Create your own class which removes padding and apply to your `col-sm-6`. Also, remove inner `.row` div. This link gives a bit diferent solution  https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-still-might-not-know#optionally-remove-the-gutter-padding-from-columns

Comment: do need a space between the boxes one above the other?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a few different grid classes. `col-<size>-<num>` where `<size>` can be `xs`, `sm`, `md`, or `lg`, and `<num>` can be an integer between (and including) `1`-`12`.

For mobile devices, you'll want to use `xs`. If you don't specify any of the larger sizes, then they'll use the same widths as the smaller one. If you change `col-sm-12` to `col-xs-12` and `col-sm-6` to `col-xs-6` I think you'll get the result you're looking for.

It also helps your inputs look more consistent and more easily themed if you give them the `form-control` class.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="group col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first-name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last-name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Bootstrap, but one way to achieve it would be to add this to your CSS:

```
.col-sm-6, .col-sm-6 .row, .col-sm-6 .row input {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is not ideal, these classes would be used repetitively in a Bootstrap page and overriding them may cause problems for other parts on the page.

Comment: @VladBardalez That may be true; however, without more code in the OP's question/Plunkr, I can't safely assume that there will be any conflicting code that this CSS would modify.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You need a space between the text box side by side right? if so try this code. You could also use col-xs-offset-1 for space between grid. This will allow you to push 1 grid away. example http://www.bootply.com/U6vlrIktq2

```
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"><br>
         </div>
 <!-- for more spacing between boxes--> 
      <div class="col-xs-5">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
     <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">

      </div>
```